# No Line Break after PHP result?

Tags: php

I've got a code to generate minimum height equal to window height (no, setting it in CSS to 100% doesn't work.)

so in the end, in a PHP file, I've got

```
min-height:<?php if (isset($_GET['width']) AND isset($_GET['height'])) { echo "". $_GET['height'] ."<br />\n"; } else { echo "<script language='javascript'>\n"; echo "  location.href=\"${_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}?${_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}" . "&width=\" + screen.width + \"&height=\" + screen.height;\n"; echo "</script>\n"; exit(); } ?>px;
```

I know that's kind of yucky, but it's just on one line. I've got this working properly and it DOES work but my end result is

```
"min-height:1080
px;"
```

and I need it to NOT be broken, just "min-height:1080px;"

I'm sure the fix is incredibly simple, it's been a long day :P

Comment: Ummm... maybe I'm not reading this correctly, but if you don't want the line break why are you adding "<br />\n" to the string?

Comment: Debug by removing characters from the code until you get the expected result. After that you'd now what was wrong

Comment: Thanks guys, I have NO idea how I overshot the br... lol

Comment: Don't forget the new-line character too (\n)... that should go as well

Comment: And the random script inside CSS property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution seems very strange. Why are you mixing up CSS and JS?

In any case, the piece of code `"<br />\n"` is causing a line break.

Anyway, *make your code readable!*

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['width']) AND isset($_GET['height'])) {
  echo '<style type="text/css">element { min-height: '.$_GET['height'] .'px; }</style>';
} else {
  echo '<script language="javascript">'.
       'location.href="'. $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] .'?'. $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] .'&width=" + screen.width + "&height=" + screen.height";'.
       '</script>';
  exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. For your first conditional block: just don't output `"<br />\n"`? I don't know why you'd do that

- in CSS
- if you don't want a newline

2. For your second:

- you can't just bung a `<script>` tag inside a CSS property and expect it to work. Consider the output of your PHP and compare it with CSS that you'd write manually.

You'll find this code *far* easier to work with if you get that mess of statements off that looooooong single line.

Answer (score 0):

You add `\n` in a few places in your loop, remove them and you should be good. And remove the  `<br />` too.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script like that..

```
min-height:<?php if (isset($_GET['width']) AND isset($_GET['height'])) { echo "". $_GET['height'] ."px;<br />\n"; } else { echo "<script language='javascript'>\n"; echo "  location.href=\"${_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}?${_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}" . "&width=\" + screen.width + \"px;&height=\" + screen.height +\"px;\n"; echo "</script>\n"; exit(); } ?>
```

Comment: "Do it like this" answers are low value on Stack Overflow because they do very little to educate/empower the OP and thousands of future researchers.